# Fourier transform of the components of bandpass signals

Tags: signal, communication, modulation

I'm referring to a book called *Communication Systems by Simon Haykin, 3rd Ed.*

It says that a band-pass signal \$s(t)\$ with mid-band frequency \$f_c\$ and bandwidth \$2W\$ can be represented as follows:
$$
s(t) = s_I(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t) - s_Q\sin(2\pi f_c t)
$$
where \$s_I(t)\$ is the in-phase component of \$s(t)\$, and \$s_Q(t)\$ is the quadrature-phase component of \$s(t)\$. Following this, it says that the Fourier transform of \$s_I(t)\$ is related to that of \$s(t)\$ by
$$
S_I(f) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
S(f-f_c) + S(f+f_c), &  -W\leq f\leq W \\ 
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Similarly for \$s_Q(t)\$,
$$
S_Q(f) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
j[S(f-f_c) - S(f+f_c)], &  -W\leq f\leq W \\ 
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I can't understand how the relations between \$S_I(f)\$ and \$S(f)\$, and \$S_Q(f)\$ and \$S(f)\$ are being derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply \$s(t)\$ with \$2\cos(2\pi f_c t)\$ and with \$-2\sin(2\pi f_c t)\$, respectively (i.e. you are actually demodulating the signal), you get:

$$s(t)\cdot2\cos(2\pi f_c t)=2s_I(t)\cos^2(2\pi f_c t)-2s_Q(t)\sin(2\pi f_c t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)=\\
=s_I(t)+[s_I(t)\cos(2\cdot2\pi f_c t)-s_Q(t)\sin(2\cdot2\pi f_c t)]$$

and

$$-s(t)\cdot2\sin(2\pi f_c t)=-2s_I(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)\sin(2\pi f_c t)+2s_Q(t)\sin^2(2\pi f_c t)=\\
=s_Q(t)-[s_I(t)\sin(2\cdot2\pi f_c t)+s_Q(t)\cos(2\cdot2\pi f_c t)]$$

Note that the terms in brackets are centered at twice the carrier frequency \$f_c\$. So in the band \$-W<f<W\$ (i.e. by low-pass filtering) we get

$$s(t)\cdot2\cos(2\pi f_c t)=s_I(t)\\
-s(t)\cdot2\sin(2\pi f_c t)=s_Q(t)$$

If you take the Fourier transform of these two equations you obtain the Fourier relations stated in your question.